# How to use @pyqtSlot decorator with other decorators in QML?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

***SOLVED:*** See my answer below. I cannot accept for 2 days.

I have a Python object derived from QObject whose methods I call from QML. These methods are of course decorated with **@pyqtSlot**. However, there is a problem when I try to combine with my own decorators like so:

```
@pyqtSlot()
@decorator
def call(self):
    print('Called!')
```

I get the error `file:X.qml:99: TypeError: Property 'call' of object X(0x7fed4c07fa50) is not a function`

This is the decorator I am using:

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapped(self):
        print('get decorated')
        return f(self)
    return wrapped
```

Could anyone clarify why this doesn't work? Some behavior of PyQt? Or am I doing something wrong?

***NOTE:*** It will work if the decorator simply returns `f`*, the problems are when the decorator returns a nested function such as* `wrapped`*.*

Comment: Change `return f ()` to `return f (self)`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I get the same results with `return f(self)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, but I'd really like to know why? I'd prefer to not use external libraries for basic language features.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [decorator](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/) library does not generate problems, in the following part I show an example:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml
import decorator


@decorator.decorator
def foo_decorator(f, *args, **kwargs):
    print('get decorated')
    return f(*args, **kwargs)


class Helper(QtCore.QObject):    
    @foo_decorator
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def call(self):
        print('Called!')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Helper()
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("obj", obj)
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('main.qml'))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Hello World"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: obj.call()
}
```

Output:

```
get decorated
Called!
```

Comment: Yes! This works... but why? I'd prefer not to use external library for basic language features.

Comment: @user985779 That library is very light, if you do not want to use it as a dependency just download the following file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micheles/decorator/master/src/decorator.py

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

def decorator(f):
    def wrapped(self):
        print('get decorated')
        return f(self)
    return wrapped

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 button")
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 320, 200)
        button = QPushButton('  \n   PyQt5\n   button\n  ', self)
        button.setIcon(QIcon("E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png"))
        button.setIconSize(QSize(34, 34))
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.setFlat(True) 
        button.move(120,70) 
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    @decorator
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Python does not generate that problem, but from QML.

Comment: My case is different. I am using a QQmlApplicationEngine and calling the Python @pyqtSlot directly from QML.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with the help of @eyllanesc's answer I was able to get to the root of the problem: which is that the decorator I was using was not preserving the function signature of my slot.

Simply changing my decorator to this fixes the problem:

```
def decorator(f):
    def call(self):
        print('get decorated')
        return f(self)
    return wrapped
```

However, this decorator isn't very reusable because of the hard-coded wrapper function name. The "correct" (only using standard libraries) way to fix this is by using the `wraps` decorator from `functools`:

```
from functools import wraps
def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def any_name_you_want(self):
        print('get decorated')
        return f(self)
    return any_name_you_want
```